# Refreshing Data in BO

Tags: java, business-objects

I am getting an error while refreshing the report in BO. What I have to do is to refresh a report in BO and find the refreshing time it taken for that. Once I find all these I have to insert those data in MySQL table.

While I am doing this I get the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ServerException: A database error occured. The database error text is: (CS) "DBDriver failed to load : C:\Program Files\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\dataAccess\connectionServer\dbd_oci.dll (The specified module could not be found.
>   )" . (WIS 10901)

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Here is the BO code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.sql.*;



import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.DocumentInstance;
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngine;
import com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngines;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.CrystalEnterprise;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.IEnterpriseSession;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.ISessionMgr;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoObject;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoObjects;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoStore;
public class RefreshWebi {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String cms="172.16.56.114";
        String username="administrator";
        String password="";
        String auth="secEnterprise";        
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Connection conn;

        IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession;

        System.out.println("success");

        Long currentTime;
        try {
            ISessionMgr sessionMgr=CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
            enterpriseSession=sessionMgr.logon(username, password,cms, auth);
            IInfoStore iStore=(IInfoStore)enterpriseSession.getService("InfoStore");    
            //bologger.entering("BOUtilities", "refreshWebIReport");
            IInfoObjects reportObjects = iStore.query("select top 1 * from ci_infoobjects where si_kind='webi'");

            ReportEngines reportEngines = (ReportEngines) enterpriseSession.getService("ReportEngines");
            ReportEngine reportEngine = reportEngines.getService(ReportEngines.ReportEngineType.WI_REPORT_ENGINE);
            Iterator it = reportObjects.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                IInfoObject reportObject = (IInfoObject) it.next();
                DocumentInstance documentInstance = reportEngine
                        .openDocument(reportObject.getID());

                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                documentInstance.refresh();
                System.out.println("Time taken to refresh "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime) / 1000);
                documentInstance.closeDocument();
                int documentID = reportObject.getID();              
                String documentName=reportObject.getTitle();                
                long refreshtime=currentTime.intValue();
                long refreshDuration=(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime) / 1000;
                int refreshtimes=(int)refreshtime;              
                int refdur=(int)refreshDuration;
                System.out.println("Document id     :"+documentID);
                System.out.println("Document name     :"+documentName);
                System.out.println("Refreshtime   :"+refreshtimes);
                System.out.println("Refresh duration  :"+refdur);

                Class.forName(driver);
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "password");               
                Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("insert into refreshtimings (documentid,documentname,refreshtime,refreshduration)values('"+documentID+"','"+documentName+"','"+refreshtimes+"','"+refdur+"')");
                conn.close();   

            }
            reportEngine.close();
            reportEngines.close();

        } catch (SDKException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to the database driver for that report is not available on the Business Objects server.  I would check to see if you get the same error inside Info View, I'm guessing that you will.

To resolve, you'll want to verify that the database type the report's connection is using is correct and that you have installed the relevant Data Source type for Business Objects.